# How do I get the ruby YAML implementation to not read beyond the YAML EOF(...)

Tags: ruby, yaml, eof

In the YAML specification it says ... is the EOF
If I do:

```
YAML.load_documents("--- abc\n--- 42\n...\nerror") { |d| puts d }
```

I should get

```
abc
42
```

But I get

```
abc
42
error
```

Unfortenely there is not much documentation about the YAML parses.
Do I have to tell the parses to honor the EOF, or does the parser not comply to the specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that according to the YAML spec (http://yaml.org/spec/current.html) that the ... only indicates the end of the current document, not the end of the file.

While the specification suggests that the only valid content beyond an end of document marker is either comments or another document, the Ruby YAML parser appears to take a rather relaxed approach and allow ... to simply split documents.

Comment: I must confess, I didn't read the specs. I read only wikipedia. I correkted the wikipedia article, so noone else misunderstands this.